# can I get NativeBase FAB to close onPress when clicking a badge?

Tags: react-native, floating-action-button, native-base

I'm currently using NativeBase's FAB and it works with no issues except that when I click on a badge which I have set to a button, I can't make it close the FAB. I'm using one of the badges to create an input and open the keyboard. This part works with no problem but I can't get it to close the FAB and when I try, it only hides all of the badges except the last one.

[FAB open after button was pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hhcl.png)
Here is a simplified version of my component

```
    const FabButton = (props) => {
    const [active, setActive] = useState(false)

    return (
        <Fab
            active={active}
            direction="up"
            containerStyle={{}}
            position="bottomRight"
            onPress={() => setActive(!active)}>

            <Icon name="arrow-up" />
            <Button onPress={props.replyToComment}>
                <Icon name="md-code-working" />
            </Button>

        </Fab>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Native Base is a heavy UI library. You can use this library https://github.com/mastermoo/react-native-action-button for the floating action button or you have to customise native base FAB component.

Here is the example:

```
 import React, {


Component
} from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import ActionButton from 'react-native-action-button';

class Basic extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Basic Example
        </Text>
        <ActionButton buttonColor="rgba(231,76,60,1)">
          <ActionButton.Item buttonColor='#9b59b6' title="New Task" onPress={() => console.log("notes tapped!")}>
            <Icon name="me-create" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
          </ActionButton.Item>
          <ActionButton.Item buttonColor='#3498db' title="Notifications" onPress={() => {}}>
            <Icon name="me-notifications-off" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
          </ActionButton.Item>
          <ActionButton.Item buttonColor='#1abc9c' title="All Tasks" onPress={() => {}}>
            <Icon name="md-done-all" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
          </ActionButton.Item>
        </ActionButton>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10
  },
  actionButtonIcon: {
    fontSize: 20,
    height: 22,
    color: 'white',
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Basic', () => Basic);
```

Comment: Thank you I'll check it out, I guess they just haven't added that feature in yet.

Comment: Tried this out and it worked perfectly. Was also really easy to set up as well, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You might be overthinking it. All you need to do is change the active state when you click on the button :)

```
const FabButton = (props) => {
const [active, setActive] = useState(false)

return (
    <Fab
        active={active}
        direction="up"
        containerStyle={{}}
        position="bottomRight"
        onPress={() => setActive(!active)}>

        <Button onPress={() => {
          props.replyToComment
          setActive(false)            // <= add this
        }}>
          <Icon name="md-code-working" />
        </Button>

    </Fab>
  );
}
```